# In an XSD file, Is it legal to use two Order Indicators for a given element?

Tags: xsd

I am creating an XSD for the following XML structure:

```
<BaseNode>
  <ParentNode1>
    <childnode/>
  </ParentNode1>
  <ParentNode2>
    <childnode/>
  </ParentNode2>
  <ParentNodeA>
    <childnode/>
  </ParentNodeA>
  <ParentNodeB>
    <childnode/>
  </ParentNodeB>
</BaseNode>
```

Where: ParentNodes 1 and 2 must appear and in order, and A and B are optional (and will only appear once each, if present), but must appear after 1 and 2 if present.

What I 'think' will work is the following, but is it valid? (specifically, the presence of both, sequence and all Order Indicators)

```
<xs:element name="BaseNode">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ParentNode1">
        ....
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ParentNode2">
        ....
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="ParentNodeA">
        ....
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ParentNodeB">
        ....
      </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:comlexType>
</xs:element>
```

I couldn't find any reference (in w3schools.com or elsewhere) to compound use of order indicators, and don't have a validator readily available.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#groups

> XML Schema stipulates that an all group must
>   appear as the sole child at the top of a content model.

example provided at the link.